# Bad Request. Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.Request header field is missing ':' separator

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, http-error, bad-request

I am writing the the Java code for HTTP Proxy application. In that browser request is not send properly, so server is giving response as

Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.Request header field is missing ':' separator. I don't understand why the error is occurring.

I am new to java so can know the solution of this question.

Request Message:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1<br>Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

I thing I have error in my request but I can't determine it.

SO anyone can help me solve my problem.

Comment: Im having the same issue posting from arduino/tinysine wifly.  I read a post about it being related to SSL on the server but Im still searching for the answer.  Did you come up with anything?

Comment: Yes, some what?. It requires handshaking with http over SSL socket for secure connection.